# running WCF service on background

Tags: xamarin.android

I am using xamarin android for my android application development.
I have WCF Post services in my activity, when I click the button that WCF Post service should run on the background service of my android app.  The service should continuously working evenafter I go to other activities and layouts.
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: you should read this page from xamarin https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is very useful to me...